# Can't solve "Sqlparameter is already contained by another SqlparameterCollection"

Tags: c#, multithreading, database-connection, sqlparameter

I am using 2 threads (from same class) in a windows service. I always getting the same error message:

```
"The SqlParameter is already contained by another SqlParameterCollection.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameterCollection.Validate(Int32 index, Object value)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameterCollection.Add(Object value)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameterCollection.Add(SqlParameter value)
   at DataBaseLayer.SqlDataBaseLayer.FillDataSetFromProcedure(String strStoredProc, ArrayList parameterCollection)
   at TestThread.StartThreads()"
```

I tried to solve the problem by creating new instances of SqlParameters and an Arraylist. I also tried to clear the arraylists at the and of my for loop in the code. This does not solve the problem. I am open to any advice.

Comment: Can you show the code of your solution?

Comment: Why are you using the same SqlParameter object against multiple commands?  Apologies if you're not, but the error message you're getting strongly suggests that you are.

Comment: Try to clear command parameters list and then add new parameters. cmd.Parameters.Clear();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to add a `SqlParameter` to a `SqlParameterCollection` twice. This may or may not be happening across threads.

If this is a multi-threading issue then all your variables should be scoped locally because, if they are not you should be implemeting sychronisation on thier access, probably with `lock`.

If this is not a concurrency problem the issue should easily be identified by doing a *Find All References* on your `SqlParameter` variable.

Either way we can help you more if you post some code.

Answer (score 2):

Dont share the same sql objects between 2 thread. Use the pool collection by SQL